# CakePHP 2.x code coverage for model code that's run in a controller

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0, xdebug

When running a controller test within a CakePHP application I would expect to see code coverage for both the controller and any other relevant code such as models used in the controller but this isn't the case for me.

Is there a configuration option for CakePHP or PHPUnit or XDebug that can include code coverage for "other" code?

NOTE: this is only an issue in the web test interface for CakePHP, on the command line, every file is included in the test coverage report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the web test interface, CakePHP 3 doesn't even have it any more.

If you really need a fancy representation I recommend you [VisualPHPUnit](https://github.com/VisualPHPUnit/VisualPHPUnit) which works with any project that uses PHPUnit 3.5+. I *guess* it will also show the correct coverage.

[image: VisualPHPUnit Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the suggested package, I'll give it a try